# Have segmented view create action in different view

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an app that tracks your speed. I have a settings page and on it there is a segmented control that switches between mph and kmh. The settings view controller and main view controller are connected to the same class. When the segmented control is in the main view it works well but once I place it into the settings view controller, even though it is connected to the same outlet, it does not work. How do I have the segmented controller control things in the main view controller?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok so I used NSUserDefaults

In my settings view controller...

```
- (IBAction)selectUnits:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"selected units");
    if (self.units.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"imperial" forKey:@"units"];
    else
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"metric" forKey:@"units"];
}
```

In my main view controller

```
 NSString *unitsSelected = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"units"];
if(unitsSelected == NULL || [unitsSelected isEqualToString:@"imperial"])
{
    speedLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", [location speed]*2.236936284];
    altitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", [location altitude]*3.2808399];
}
else
{
    speedLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", [location speed]*3.6];
    altitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", [location altitude]];
}
```

This works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Like any `UIControl`, you can use `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` to add any object as a target for the control's events.

Read [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIControl/addTarget%3aaction%3aforControlEvents%3a) more in the documentation.
And also the [Target-Action guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/TargetAction.html).

Comment: I simply do not get it

Comment: @msweet168 See this article: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/TargetAction.html

Comment: Ok, so now how to I trigger an action that is in a different view?

Comment: The user triggers an action by touching the control. All targets get notified of the action.

Comment: Perhaps you have not explained what you want to do properly.

Comment: You have to add the "main view controller" as a target to the segmented control that's in your "settings" view controller.

Comment: how do I add the main view controller as a target.